# Delete selected Item from array in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code:

`<button type="button" className='button button-delete' onClick={() => deleteFuncionarioFromProject(funcionarioDetails.uid)}><i className="pi pi-trash"></i></button>`

onClick of the button does this:

```
const deleteFuncionarioFromProject = async (funcionarioKey) => {
        
        console.log(funcionarioKey) //get funcionario key from DB to delete from project:

        const docRef = doc(db, "projetos", detalhesProjetoKey);
        await updateDoc(docRef, {
            funcionarios: arrayRemove(funcionarioKey)
        });

    }
```

I'm expecting to delete the selected "funcionario"(employee) from the array of firebase.

This is my db
[image]

For example, I click the second worker and it should delete it from the array, but I get this error:

`FirebaseError: No document to update: +projectKey`

I have tried other solutions from here, and none of it works.

Comment: What is the value of `funcionarioKey` inside your reference? Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: The value of the funcionarioKey, is like if I click in the first employee to remove ( number 0 in db ) I get the " jd46rUDO08dVeGmJFVjdsfWty0D3 " .

Comment: Can you please check the second part of my comment?

Comment: Yes, it is done already

Comment: What values does this variable `detalhesProjetoKey` hold?

Comment: The key of the project, in that case is the "0.bt4f4xp9fm9"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perform an update to a particular document, you have to create a document reference that points to that document. Since you are passing the project ID (`0.bt4f4xp9fm9`) and **not** the actual document ID (`PHXAaDEFt49ptVzn40wf`), the update operation will fail. So if you need to remove the `jd46rUDO08dVeGmJFVjdsfWty0D3` ID from within the `projetos` array that exists inside the document that has this ID `PHXAaDEFt49ptVzn40wf`, then you have to change the `docRef` in your code into:

```
const docRef = doc(db, "projetos", "PHXAaDEFt49ptVzn40wf");
//
```

If you, however, don't know the value of the document ID, and you only have the project ID which is stored in the `key` field, then you have to perform a query and find that document. Once you find the document, read it, and right after that perform the update.

In your case, I recommend you store the document ID, so you can only create a document reference and use `arrayRemove`.

Comment: Hey João. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Sorry, yesterday I started searching about how can I get the document ID and the only thing i could find, was for the document data, do you have some link that I can read about to learn? I'm kinda new to this.

But I understand your point, and its probably why it doesnt work.

Comment: Recommendations for tutorial resources to read are forbidden, here on StackOverflow. In your case, a better resource than the official documentation, I cannot recommend.

Comment: Did you actually try the solution in my answer? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, the code you give me it worked perfectly, but the problem is that I cant use the document ID written, I need to place it in a variable.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. However, if for example, after you solve a problem, and you have another problem that derives from the initial one, it's best to post a new question, here on StackOverflow, in which you should show us what you have tried and what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Can I help you with information regarding the initial problem of using the project ID, rather than using de document ID?

Comment: Im trying to map the "funcionario" from the main page insted of doing it from a component, if it works this way, I would let you know, otherwise, I can create a new question with the info :D